# What is the best practice for implementing a comparison method who's comparison type is chosen at runtime?

Tags: javascript

Say you are given *A* and want to compare it to *B*. Sometimes you can to check if *A* < *B*, and sometimes you want to check if *A* > *B*. You want to do this in one method, that takes a "comparison type" in some form as one of its arguments. Is there a "best-practice" for how this should be done?

An example of how I do this now is included for clarity. When the *a* flag is passed in, the comparison method is "greater than", and vice versa.

```
function func(a, b, c) {
    var cmp = a ? gt : lt;
    if (cmp(b, c)) {
        return 'Hi';
    }
    return 'Bye';
}

function lt(a, b) {
    return a < b;
}

function gt(a, b) {
    return a > b;
}
```

Comment: Your duplicated code always returns Hi if b > c disregarding a

Comment: @juvian Oops, fixed that lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do this when dealing with sorting when you need to choose between ascending and descending:

```
var cmp = a ? 1 : -1
if(b*cmp > c*cmp){ // not sure if you want a > or a  < here
    return 'Hi'
}else{
    return 'Bye'
}
```

A shorten version would be using boolean logic with a xor: (note that it gives wrong result for a b==c case)

```
function func(a, b, c) {
    if ((b > c)^!a) {
        return 'Hi';
    }
    return 'Bye';
}
```

Explanation: If you make a table with the 4 possibilities, you have:

a   |  b > c | expected output

true |  true |   Hi

true |  false |  Bye

false | true |   Bye

false | false |  Hi

If you consider the Hi as true and Bye as false, if a and b > c are equal you want a true, if not you want a false. Xor does a similar thing, if the 2 are equal it gives false and if they are different it gives true. Invert that and we have the result we want

If you make same table but taking into account equal cases, you can end up with this:

```
  function func(a, b, c) {
    if(b == c || (b > c)^a){
      return 'Bye'
    }
    return 'Hi'
  }
```

Comment: That second one is really friggin cool lol, could you give a word description of how it works?

Comment: @KthProg added ;). Not that if the values are equal, it will give wrong result

Comment: I like the solutions, but that's the kind of code I would hate you for if I had to fix it two hours before the deadline :-)

Comment: I know this will kill people, but that 2nd and last ones are the correct answers to me. Us programmers should increase our understanding of less-used conditionals like Xor.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
if((a && b > c) || (!a && b < c)) {
    return 'Hi';
} else {
    return 'Bye';
}
```

I would argue that this is still easily readable and understandable, covers the described requirements and keeps the code concise and free of duplications.

Comment: This is definitely the right solution currently in a real programming environment, but I chose the other answer for different reasons.